# VBA: I need to write both a function and a calling sub to do the following

Tags: vba, excel

In the main subroutine, I have to get two user inputs ((1) range address (e.g., A1:C50), (2) Name String (e.g., James)), and call the function subroutine (by passing the inputs as arguments), and printout the result through Message Box as to whether the name exists or doesn't exist in the range.

Both the search range and the name should be input from the users. How do I write the Function subRoutine and the calling sub? This is what I have so far.

```
Function NameExists(name As String, area As Range) As Boolean



If name = area.Value Then
    NameExists = True

Else
    NameExists = False

End If


End Function



Sub Main()
Dim NameExists As Boolean
Dim name As String

name = InputBox("Enter a Name")
area = InputBox("Enter a Range")


If NameExists = True Then
MsgBox name & " Has Been Found"
Else
 MsgBox name & " Has Not Been Found"
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually call the Function that checks if it exists and pass the name and area variables that you've had the user input. Here is a somewhat crude example:

```
    Sub Main()

    Dim nm As String
    Dim ar As String

    nm = InputBox("Enter a Name")
    ar = InputBox("Enter a Range")

    If NameExists(nm, ar) = True Then

        MsgBox nm & " Has Been Found"

    Else

        MsgBox nm & " Has Not Been Found"

    End If

    End Sub

    Private Function NameExists(name As String, area As String) As Boolean

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(area)

    For Each myCell In myRange

        If myCell.Value = name Then

            NameExists = True

            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    Set myRange = Nothing

    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Is there a way to have the user select the range as opposed to typing it? I know this code looks similar to:
    area = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
        "Please Select a Range", _
        Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=8)
But how would I implement that in the function?

Comment: If you want to do that, then you will probably want to forget about using the  second Textbox altogether. Instead, create a macro and assign a button to the toolbar that pops up an InputBox to get the name to search for, then takes the selected Range and passes them both to the function in my code. That way, the user highlights a Range and then clicks a button. That would be a better way of doing it I think.